# Правильное построение предложения. Где может стоять сказуемое?

Tags: грамматика, члены-предложения

Добрый вечер.
Подскажите, *где можно найти правила по грамотному построению предложений?*
Сложность в том, что я не могу объяснить и опереться **на конкретное правило.**

Есть ли такое правило: **сказуемое не может стоять в конце предложения?**
Например: **"Правильно предложение составляйте"**.

*Принципиально ли, что сказуемое стоит в конце?* Мне кажется, это не правильно, но не могу найти правила.
И ещё: **"Чётко и ясно слова проговаривайте".**

Answer (score 4):

В русском языке [свободный порядок слов в предложении](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2). Положение сказуемого в конце приведенных предложений — не принципиально.

Например, все эти предложения являются грамматически корректными:

> Проговаривайте четко и ясно слова.
>   Проговаривайте слова четко и ясно.
>   Четко и ясно проговаривайте слова.
>   Слова проговаривайте четко и ясно.
>   Четко и ясно слова проговоривайте.
>   Слова четко и ясно проговаривайте.

Стилистически важно чтобы слова сочетались между собой. Например, первый и последний варианты сложнее для восприятия т.к. дополнение («слова») оказалось оторвано от сказуемого к которому оно относится («проговаривайте»).

Определенные рекоммендации по порядку слов в предложении есть в «[Справочнике по правописанию и стилистике](http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xlii.html)» Д.Э. Розенталя. Например, по примеру:

> XLII. Порядок слов в предложении.
>   ...
>   § 180. Место дополнения в предложении
>   Дополнение обычно следует за управляющим словом, например: вычитать рукопись, исправление опечаток, готовы к набору.
>   ...
>   § 181. Место обстоятельств в предложении
>   Обстоятельства  образа действия, выраженные наречиями на -о, -е, обычно ставятся впереди глагола-сказуемого, например: Перевод точно отражает содержание оригинала; Мальчик вызывающе смотрел на нас; Гаврюшка густо покраснел и бурно запротестовал… (Гладков); Вокзал быстрее и быстрее уплывал назад… (Г. Николаева); Мостовая гладко белела (Антонов).

Нужно заметить, что это только общие стилистические рекоммендации. Альтернативные варианты корректны и могут использоваться для интонационного выделения слов, либо для смысловой связи с другими предложениями.

Answer (score 4):

1) Возьмем простейший текст: Весна наконец наступила. Лёд на реке растаял, трава зазеленела, вот и грачи прилетели.

**Во всех случаях сказуемое стоит в конце предложения, так стоит ли искать правило о том, что "сказуемое не может стоять в конце предложения"?**

В том же тексте можно изменить порядок слов: Наступила весна. Растаял  лёд на реке, зазеленела трава, прилетели грачи.

Что-нибудь изменилось? Наверное, авторский взгляд. В первом случае мы наблюдаем за предметами (лед, трава, грачи), а во втором случае фиксируем действия (растаял, зазеленела, прилетели).

**Порядок слов в русском языке — вещь непростая**, эту тему проходят в школе (построение текста, структура текста). Носители языка обычно строят свою речь интуитивно, но в любом случае надо внимательно наблюдать  за порядком слов в любом тексте, с которым вы работаете.  Перестановка слов, во-первых,  не всегда возможна, а во-вторых, может повлиять на  смысл сказанного.

2) **Чётко и ясно слова проговаривайте** - здесь явная инверсия, похоже на отрывок из авангардистского стихотворения, в обычной речи такой порядок слов вряд ли применим.

Это теоретически можно сказать, что любой порядок возможен, **но всё зависит от контекста, например:** Не спешите, проговаривайте слова четко и ясно. Следите за правильным ударением, четко и ясно проговаривайте слова.